# SSIS: How to automatically rerun a package after it has completed?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, ssms

I need my package to run again directly after it has finished. How to do it ? Should I use the SQL Server Agent ?

I need to do it this way because the user won't have access to SSIS, but only to Management Studio.

I used a WMI Event Watcher Task to look indefinitely for a particular file being droped in a folder "Drop". When it happens, the package executes, and then I uses a File System Task to remove the file from the folder where it was dropped to another folder "Archved".

Finally, the user should be able to rerun the package by dropping the same file in the folder that triggers the package "Drop".

My problem is that I have to click on "run package" after it has finished. I would like ssis to do it by itself.

Is it possible?

EDITED:

When adding a For Loop Container with EvalExpression 1=1, the following two Execute SQL Tasks never run. Without the Loop they do but only once straight to the end.

[image]

Comment: Does that mean that if should run every time after it completes? So runs indefinitely, or just runs against after the first time?

Comment: Indefinitely @Larnu

Comment: If re-run is a requirement, perhaps the easiest way is to duplicate SSIS step twice in SQL Agent.

Comment: I don't understand. If the file watcher triggers the package when the first file appears, won't it trigger the package again when the user drops another file?

Comment: No because for the File Watcher to detect the dropped file, It has to be running. In my case, it's waiting indefinitely but only starting from the moment we press the green triangle.
So, when the package completes, the WMI Event Watcher is set as green and is no more looking for another file being dropped.

So I need the package to rerun by itself.

Comment: Is it possbile to explicitely tell to ssis to rerun when a package is completed?

Comment: Have you tried to use a For Loop Container and set its EvalExpression to 1==1?? Just saying...

Comment: How are you triggering the SSIS package? Is it being run manually through VS or via SQL agent job or job scheduler of some sort?

Comment: I run it manually through VS

Comment: 1) Click on the green triangle
2) Drop the file

Comment: Maybe I should link to the file watcher an sql task that executes the other boxes by assigning a variable.

Comment: Well, I think you might be able to get away with using the SQL Agent job and schedule it to run every 1-5 mins interval or whatever the average run time is for your package. That way it will keep running indefinitely.

Comment: You have to include all the tasks inside the For Loop Container, it should work. It's not a good approach though.

Comment: This answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31105/125215 or possibly this one will solve your issue: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/226051/125215 You might need to update the scripts a bit with your job names and possibly additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be setup using SQL Agent something like this:

**Step 1:** Create a new job using SSMS:

[image]

**Step 2:** Add a new job step to run the SSIS package

[image]

**Step 3:** Add a new schedule to define the interval for the job run (adjust it to meet your requirements)

[image]

In this case, for each run, the file watcher step in the package would wait for the file to be dropped and run the job successfully once the file is dropped/found.

**Note:** Please test this on your non-prod environment to ensure it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest approach to achieve that is to create another package, lets call it master package. Add two [Execute Package Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-package-task?view=sql-server-2017) that execute the same package.

For more information about Execute Package Task, check the following link:

- [SQL SERVER – The Basics of the Execute Package Task](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/02/12/sql-server-the-basics-of-the-execute-package-task-notes-from-the-field-067/)